# Who is the blonde woman in the opening of "Slayers NEXT"?

Tags: slayers

In the opening of *Slayers NEXT* at around 1:20, there's a blonde girl.

[image: A side-face of a blonde woman]

However, there is no female character that has blonde hair. I am sure it is not Filia since she appears only in *TRY*. It isn't Lina's sister since she appears in the opening as well (similar to how she appears at the beginning of *NEXT*).

Who is she?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**She is Lina Inverse**, or to be exact (**spoiler from the last episode of *Slayers NEXT***)

> **[The Lord of Nightmares](http://kanzaka.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_of_Nightmares), possessing Lina Inverse**.

---

From a Japanese Q&A site [OKWAVE answered by l_gaim_mk1 on August 2008](https://okwave.jp/qa/q4284877/a12869293.html),

> ＮＥＸＴ放送当時（１９９６年）にも言われました。そのネタ。
>
> 最初は、当時まだ姿が登場していなかった獣王ゼラス＝メタリオムとも、ルナ・インバースとも言われました。
>
> 結局、原作者やアニメスタッフから出た回答が、リナ・インバースです。
>
> > 但し、ロード・オブ・ナイトメアに乗っ取られたヴァージョンである。と。
>
> そういう風に議論が飛び交うのが狙いだったとか。
>
> 当時のアニメ雑誌の記述より。

Rough translation

> This was also told at the time *NEXT* was being broadcasted (1996). That topic.
>
> At first, it was speculated to be Luna Inverse or Greater Beast Zelas Metallium, who has never appeared yet at that time.
>
> In the end, the answer that came from the author and the anime staff was, Lina Inverse.
>
> > However, the version that was possessed by The Lord of Nightmares.
>
> Maybe it was aimed for the discussion to fly about like that?
>
> Taken from an anime magazine at that time.

Comment: I admit the lack of credibility in this answer because there's no primary source (the name of the anime magazine), but it's not that easy to find. On the other hand, 3 other answers, another Japanese fansite, and the Japanese Wikipedia also agreed with the character's appearance (not really a conclusion, but if it serves to add more credibility...)

Answer (score 1):

L-sama / Lord of nightmares. Here's an interview explaining their hair colors https://archive.is/2CAcK